# iOS Change app Language doesn't take effect

Tags: ios, localization, nsbundle

I am changing my iOS application preferred language dynamically using this setting:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"ar"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Then I load a localised resource file from the main NSBundle object, but the loaded file isn't of the new language, it's loaded in the default english language until I restart the application totally then it loads the arabic localisation.

I want to force NSBundle to load the resource file in the new language @"ar" not the language been set when app starts. How?

Comment: This method only works if you restart your app.

Comment: Is there a method working immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is a hacky way to get what you need, and requires app restart to take effect.

It is best to use `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle` instead of `NSLocalizedString`, and provide the bundle for that language.

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ar" ofType:@"lproj"];
NSBundle* ar_bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"str", nil, ar_bundle, @"comment");
```

If you put the bundle in a global scope, you can create a macro for ease:

```
#define ARLocalizedString(str, cmt) NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(str, nil, ar_bundle, cmt)
```

Comment: This here doesn't require an App restart? Thanks.

Comment: So will I use this method instead of [NSBundle mainBundle] when loading nib files too?

Comment: @AhmedSaid Yes, use the `ar_bundle` when loading nibs.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and its working fine without restarting the app:

```
//Use this in constants
#ifdef NSLocalizedString
#undef NSLocalizedString
#endif
#define NSLocalizedString(str, cmt) NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(str, nil, newLangbundle, cmt)
```

newLangbundle --> Define a global variable in .pch and vary it according to language selection using this,

```
 NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"th" ofType:@"lproj"];
 newLangbundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize user defaults after changing the language:
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] default synchronize]